# DateTime.ParseExact is not doing what i want it to do

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

When use the .ParseExact() method for the DateTime, i always get the same output as the string i put in. Here is my code:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Backoffice, Manager")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FilmShowCreate(FilmShowViewModel newFilmShow)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValidField("FilmId") && ModelState.IsValidField("Time"))
        {
            DateTime unformattedDateTime = newFilmShow.Date.Date + newFilmShow.Time.TimeOfDay;
            string dateString = unformattedDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            DateTime dbDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

            FilmShow filmShow = new FilmShow
            {
                  Film = filmRepository.GetFilm(newFilmShow.FilmId),
                  Cinema = cinemaRepository.GetCinema(newFilmShow.CinemaId),
                  ThreeDimensional = newFilmShow.ThreeDimensional,
                  Date = dbDate,
                  SpecialEvent = newFilmShow.SpecialEvent
            };

            filmShowsRepository.AddShow(filmShow);

            return View("SuccesfullFilmShowCreate");
```

The string dateString is formatted good, but it is a string and I need to store it in the database as a format DateTime like this "year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds". But for whatever reason the ParseExact doesn't seem to work in my case. The DateTime format i get is "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't do what you want because, well, that function isn't *supposed* to do what you are describing.

`ParseExact` simply indicates that the **input** must match the given format in order to be used (and not throw an exception). It is a counterpart to `Parse` which will accept any valid Date/Time format. *It has absolutely no bearing on the future format of any string representation of the `DateTime` object it creates.*

If you want to **output** it in a given format, pass your format string into `ToString` before sending that string to the database. Of course, if you are using something like EF, the conversion is done for you and it shouldn't matter.

Example:

```
string myFormattedDateTime = dbDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Reading your question more closely, I realize that you seem to think that DateTime has some "stored" format. It does not. DateTime is just a collection of numbers that hold the information required to represent a date and time. The format you are describing *only* exists in string representations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I understand your story, but it doesn't really solve my actual problem. When i run a seed method when doing a migration, i add a datetime like this : Date = new DateTime(2017, 03, 08, 14, 00, 00) resulting in a date 2017-03-08 14:00:00 which is what i want, but when i add a datetime using my repository i get the following format 2017-08-03 14:00:00 which is the day and month switched around. I really don't know whats causing this, but it's really frustrating.

Comment: @NickBurggraaff sorry, I think you'll need a bit more debugging on your end. Rest assured `ParseExact` isn't your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help nevertheless! Fixed it by assigning the day to the month and the month to the day haha. Not a very clean fix but is works... Thats what matters.